# What kind of algorithm do I need to find all the linear sequences from a set with defined rules?

Tags: algorithm

I need help finding all the possible solutions to this problem.
I have no experience with computer science or building algorithms so I thought someone here might help me figure out what can I do to solve it or maybe even help solve it‍♂️

On the attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc9Mf.jpg) there are 24 rows of domino-like chips - on the bottom half they have two sides with a letter assigned to each. Top half of a chip contains a number of a row it belongs to, to help identify it.

I need to find all the possible linear sequences of chips that comply with the following rules:

• A chip from each of the 24 rows must be used, but only one.

• Chips connect in a sequence by common letter (like dominos connect by common number), e.g. 9_CF > 6_FD > 4_DC > 13_CG etc.
Or you might think of it like that Last Letter Game where every next word should start with the last letter of a preceding word.

• Each possible sequence must start with a 'C'

I tried printing it, cutting out all the pieces and tried manually finding all the combinations, but my brain exploded from overwhelm after like 10 minutes. It seems like it will take ages doing it manually where some kind of computer algorithm might do it in a few seconds

I'm a little bit familiar with programming so I could in theory write an algorithm myself with some help and directions on the logic and structure of the code. I don't even know which programming language to use for such problem

Really sorry if this is not a place for such a question, I'm all out of hope on finding someone to help me.

Comment: You can choose whichever programming language you're most comfortable with. An appropriate strategy for this would be [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

Comment: @Stef Thank you so much! Looking into it☺